# Selenium (python) text deletes on its own

Tags: python, selenium, automation

Selenium is able to find these elements and send_text to them, but right after the text is written it is automatically deleted. Am I calling .send_text() wrong, or am I finding the wrong element to interact with?

This is a popup frame dialog, but I can't seem to focus on the frame. I'm not even sure I need to as selenium still interacts with the text fields.

Here is the javascript:

```
<div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Patient ID</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input data-ng-model="subject.Code" data-custom-error="Patient ID already exists in this center" class="ng-valid ng-dirty" data-original-title="" type="text">
                    <i class="required-field" style="top:inherit">*</i>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is one method I have been using:

```
patientID = 'testID'
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@data-ng-model='subject.Code']").send_keys(patientID)
```

also,

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".controls > input[data-ng-model='subject.Code']").send_keys(patientID)
```

As I said, both find the correct element and send text but the text is immediately deleted. Any ideas, I'm stuck.

I'm using firefox, but the same happens in chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked if there is any javascript code in the page listening to changes to the input field and deleting its contents?

Comment: this is not an answer.

Comment: unfortunately, new users are barred from comments untill they get X points. 
 I am assuming that was the rational. :/

Comment: Yes, I did try to interact with the javacode and that seemed like a promising solution. But I ended up writing a function to make selenium type slower and that solved my problem.

I think the field was looking for fake users and ignoring my inputs because they were coming to fast.